# Show that each of the following are homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that the following maps are group homomorphisms and find their kernels:

1) $\theta: \Bbb Z \rightarrow GL_2$

$\theta(n) = $$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & n \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$

My attempt:

Let $y\in\Bbb Z$ such that

$\theta(y) = $$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & y \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$

Then $\theta(n) \theta(y) = $$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & y \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
 $$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & n \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$ 
=  \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & y+n \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$ = $\theta(n+y)$

So $\theta: \Bbb Z \rightarrow GL_2$ is a homomorphism. And I think ker$\theta = \theta(0)$ as  \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix} is the identity of the $GL_2$

(Is that an efficient enough proof?)

2) $\theta:\Bbb Q$ \ {0} $\rightarrow GL_2(\Bbb Q)$ given by 
$\theta(a) =  \begin{pmatrix}
        a & 0 \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$

My attempt:

Let there exist $b \in \Bbb Q$ \ {0} such that $\theta(b) =  \begin{pmatrix}
        b & 0 \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$

Then we have:

$\theta(a)\theta(b)= \begin{pmatrix}
        a & 0 \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
        b & 0 \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$ = $ \begin{pmatrix}
        ab & 0 \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$ = $\theta(ab)$

ker$\theta= \theta(1)$

etc

Is this correct way to answer this question?

This isn't homework, by the way. I'm revising for an exam I have on monday and these questions were in our practice sheets. If you have more tips for me on my first ever Abstract Algebra exam please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

You’re fine, if a bit clumsy, with verifying that the maps are homomorphisms, but there are some problems with the kernels.

Let’s look at the first problem. To show that $\theta$ is a homomorphism, you really should start with two arbitrary elements of $\Bbb Z$ and verify that $\theta$ has the homomorphism property with respect to these two elements.

> Let $m,n\in\Bbb Z$. Then $$\theta(m+n)=\pmatrix{1&m+n\\0&1}=\pmatrix{1&m\\0&1}\pmatrix{1&n\\0&1}=\theta(m)\theta(n)\;,$$ so $\theta$ is a homomorphism.

Your statement that $\ker\theta=\theta(0)$ doesn’t make sense: $\ker\theta$ is by definition a subset of $\Bbb Z$, while $\theta(0)$ is an element of $GL_2$, so they can’t possibly be equal. Go back to the definition:

$$\ker\theta=\left\{n\in\Bbb Z:\theta(n)=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}\right\}\;,$$

since $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$ is the identity element of $GL_2$. Now you can argue as follows.

> Suppose that $n\in\ker\theta$; then $\theta(n)=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$ by the definition of kernel. On the other hand, $\theta(n)=\pmatrix{1&n\\0&1}$ by the definition of $\theta$, so $n=0$. Thus, $\ker\theta=\{0\}$.

You can also conclude that $\theta$ is injective (one-to-one), since its kernel is trivial, but that’s not part of the problem.

The other problem is dealt with similarly.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I always feel like I understand the concepts but have a lot of trouble knowing which proof-language to use to verify something. Thank you, Mr. Scott!

Comment: @Siyanda: You’re very welcome.